# Revoke a 'Revert' Commit after many other commits have been pushed

Tags: git, github

We are facing a strange scenario. The state of repository is certainly showing loss of work of past few days. Upon investigating Git Log we found out that one of the commit was a 'revert commit' and it has reverted the change back to several days. After that many more commits have already been pushed which we have to retain.

So we have a state A, and then State B (revert commit) and the State C. We have to goto State D which will be built from state A and work from B to C. We have to drop a single commit B from between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A revert commit is a commit like any other. There is nothing special about it. So if you don't want the revert, revert the revert again.

By way of example:

```
D - reverting 'reverting 'questionable work''
|
C - important work
|
B - reverting 'questionable work'
|
A - questionable work
```

Someone reverted A (`git revert A`) because it seemed questionable but after C happened you find out that the questionable work actually was useful. So you revert again (`git revert B`). It doesn't matter how many commits A, B/D or C are: Your important work C could consist of many commits and so could your reverts.

Note that if C introduced changes that are based on the revert, you may run into merge conflicts that you have to resolve.